# Evaluating a function over a list in Python - without using loops

Tags: python, sympy

There is a problem in Python which involves the evaluation of a function over a list of numbers which are provided as inputs to the following function:

f(y) = sin(3y + pi/3) + cos(4y - pi/7)

I don't think MathJax tools are available on StackOverflow so the above is the best I can do.

There are four outputs to the function: An array or list containing the values obtained by the function for each element of the input list, the minimum and maximum values in the output array / list, and an array or list of the differences between successive values obtained by the function.

Here is the code so far. We assume that only sensible inputs are passed to the function.

```
import sympy
def minMaxDiffValues(lst):
    y = sympy.symbols('y')
    f = sympy.sin(3*y + sympy.pi/3) + sympy.cos(4*y - sympy.pi/7)
    values = []
    for n in lst:
        values.append(f.subs(y,n))
    differences = []
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):
        differences.append(values[i + 1] - values[i])
    print values
    print min(values)
    print max(values)
    print differences
```

As far as I know, the above code gets the job done; I've opted to work with lists, even though I am familiar with numpy. I'll replace the print statements with a single return statement; for now I'm printing the outputs to make sure that they are correct.

The only issue is that the problem prevents the use of loops; thus I am uncertain as to how to approach such a problem for the first and last function outputs.

**Is it possible to write the above function without using any loops?**

Comment: In `numpy`, when we talk about doing something without loops we really mean moving the loops to compiled code, using the available `numpy` whole array operations.  What you seek is trivial in `numpy`, using that definition of `without loops`.  `(lambda y: np.sin(3*y+np.pi/3)+np.cos(4*y-np.pi/7))(np.array(lst))`

Comment: While a list comprehension is clean alternative to your append loop, I think a more interesting question is whether `sympy` offers a nice way of do the `subs` for a list of values, may with a `sympy.Matrix`.  It may not offer the speed advantage of a `numpy` style array application.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html discusses some ways of evaluating a sympy expression numerically, and gives an idea of the relative speeds.  `subs` is simplest, but slowest.  `lambdify` can generate a Python object that evaluates faster, or a `numpy` one that's even faster for array inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use list comprehensions:

```py
import sympy

def minMaxDiffValues(lst):
    y = sympy.symbols('y')
    f = sympy.sin(3*y + sympy.pi/3) + sympy.cos(4*y - sympy.pi/7)

    values = [f.subs(y,n) for n in lst]
    differences = [values[i+1] - values[i] for i in range(len(values)-1)]

    print(values)
    print(min(values))
    print(max(values))
    print(differences)
```

If you wanted to, you could also use the `pairwise` recipe from [the itertools module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html):

```py
import itertools
import sympy


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def minMaxDiffValues(lst):
    y = sympy.symbols('y')
    f = sympy.sin(3*y + sympy.pi/3) + sympy.cos(4*y - sympy.pi/7)

    values = [f.subs(y,n) for n in lst]
    differences = [y - x for (x, y) in pairwise(values)]

    print(values)
    print(min(values))
    print(max(values))
    print(differences)
```

Comment: Quick clarification on the list comprehensions - so using the "for" keyword **inside** a pair of list brackets does not constitute a use of loops? If so, that's a very elegant solution.

Comment: Much as I like them, I view list comprehensions as loops.  It's a clean way of expressing the list append type of loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` is a way to apply a function to a list of values in a compact fashion:

```
>>> from sympy import y, pi
>>> f = lambda y: sin(3*y + pi/3) + cos(4*y - pi/7)
>>> vals = list(map(f, lst))
>>> d = lambda i: vals[i] - vals[i-1]
>>> difs = list(map(d, range(1, len(vals))))
```

And there is no visible 'for'. But as @hpaulj notes, there's one under the hood somewhere.